# Keep default implementations of member functions in a specialized template class

Tags: c++, templates

Currently trying to write some vector maths code, and I would like to do it by specializing the various structures to different sizes. However, in this specialization, the member functions of the unspecialized structure get lost.

Minimum example:

```cpp
template <size_t N> struct Vector {
  float data[N];

  inline float &operator[](size_t i) { return data[i]; }

  inline constexpr float &operator[](size_t i) const { return data[i]; }
};

template <> struct Vector<2> {
  union {
    float data[2];
    struct {
      float x, y;
    };
  };
};

int main() {
  Vector<2> v2 = {1, 3};
  std::cout << v2[0] << " = " << v2.x << " | " << v2[1] << " = " << v2.y
            << std::endl;
}
```

This code does not compile as the `operator[]` on `v2` is not defined. This seems like a very common use case of specialization so is it possible to do this, if not is there a language design reason why this isn't possible?

(I know I can duplicate the code into the specialized structure, I'm trying to avoid that)

Comment: This is the case, because it offers the most freedom to the programmer. You can implement a specialization basically independent from the primary template. A common work around would be to have a `template<size_t N> struct vector_impl` with the operator and let both the primary template and the specialization inherit from it.

Comment: In this case, inheritance wouldn't work because I want to union the named accessors with the data storage, and I don't see the whole offering freedom to the programmer, if the programmer wanted it to be different there is nothing stopping them from doing that, while this forces code duplication. Still though thanks ^^

Comment: Type punning isn't allowed in C++. Your usage is pedantically UB.

Comment: inheritance would work: data is in the specializations `VectorData`. `operator[]` would go in the generic derived class.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is type punning by any reasonable definition as the only use here is of a union in which all types are the same and all potential sizes and offsets are the same meaning there is no danger of bad memory interpretation. So pedantically maybe, but practically no. In any case, it's irrelevant to the main question though.

Comment: @alexagriffin You must not reason about UB like that. Your optimizer is allowed to – and does – assume that your program does not contain any UB as defined by the language spec. It optimizes accordingly which makes your kind of reasoning completely unreliable. However, at least GCC explicitly allows union-based type punning. I seem to recall that Clang and MSVC do as well.

Comment: I've just tested a similar case (the union stuff) in g++, clang, msvc, and an internal compiler and they all work as expected and produce similar assembly. So still, practically no. This has strayed though, thanks for the info on inheritance ^^